# Getting alert if no data is receiving using kibana alert

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We want to create alert if no data is receiving is from last 15 minute. We have tried with the watcher it worked for us but we can't go as in watcher the alert status does not change like as in alert we have active , recover options we have.

I tried with Index Threshold alert but i can't able to create it. Please if any one has solution update me here

Answer (score 0):

Check this article to setup an alert `if the document count for specific index less than 0 in last 5 minutes` with an out-of-bucks alerting solution via Kibana UI.

https://medium.com/@kulekci/alerting-with-elasticsearch-e40492fcf126

Official documentation is here :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/apm-alerts.html